# Which part of my proof is wrong( $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is not compact in $\mathbb{Q}$)

Tags: general-topology

We know that $[0,1]$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$, then for an arbitrary open cover, $O_i,\; i \in \{1,2,...\}$, there exists a finite subcover, $O_{i_k},\; k=\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $[0,1] \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^nO_{i_k}$. Since for each $Q_{i_k}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, $O_{i_k}\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$. Now, 
$$\begin{align*}
[0,1] \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^nO_{i_k} \Rightarrow [0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q} &\subset \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nO_{i_k}\right)\cap \mathbb{Q} \\
& = \bigcup^n_{k=1}(O_{i_k}\cap\mathbb{Q})
\end{align*}$$
Since $O_{i_k}\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$ and we have a finite union of them, $ [0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q} $ is compact in $\mathbb{Q}$.

But Clearly, it is not compact when I checked the answer, meaning that I made a mistake somewhere. Can anyone please fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: 
$$
[0, 1]\cap \Bbb Q = \big([0, \frac1\pi) \cup (\frac1\pi, 1]\big)\cap \Bbb Q
$$
where $[0, 1/\pi) \cup (1/\pi, 1]$ clearly isn't compact.

Your mistake is to assume that a collection of open sets in $\Bbb R$ that covers $[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q$ must cover $[0,1]$.

Comment: Nice. +1 for only pointing out the error in OP's solution and not giving him your own solution.

Comment: @Arther But I started the proof from defining open coverings that cover $[0,1]$ and they covers $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$...?

Comment: @user1292919 But that means you are not considering all possible open covers of $[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q$; you are only considering the ones that happen to cover the entire $[0,1]$. To show that a set is compact, you need to show something about _all_ open covers, not just the nice ones.

Comment: @Arthur Oh! I understood now Thanks :)